# Import arcpy to spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, arcpy, arcmap

I am trying to work with Arcpy from Spyder, but when I import the Arcpy package, I receive the following message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arcpy'
```

I tried to install Arcpy package 2.7 (my ArcMap and IDLE version) through Anaconda prompt:

```
conda install arcpy=2.7 -c esri
```

but I wasn't successful.

So far I've been working with IDLE, but what I really want is to work with arcpy directly from Spyder. Specially to extract vector and raster data (geometry coordinates, atribute table values, etc), so that I can work with it afterwards.

Is there any way of achieving that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you still not have arcpy in your Spyder?

Comment: What do you mean you weren't successful?

Comment: @Pfalbaum thanks for the suggestion. However, I still get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arcpy'` every time I import arcpy in spyder editor. That's what I meant by "unsuccessful".
Also, I check my environments in anaconda prompt. I get the following:

`(base) C:\Users\Sarocas>conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\Sarocas\anaconda3
py27                     C:\Users\Sarocas\anaconda3\envs\py27`

I created this py27 environment because that's the version of python that comes with ArcMap. I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Also, I'm not using ArcGISPro.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure if you were using Pro or ArcMap. Have you tried changing the Python interpreter in your Spyder Preferences? ```CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+P``` or Tools>Preferences>Python interpreter>Use the following interpreter. You can try setting it to where your ArcMap python.exe lives. Or in an Anaconda Powershell Prompt>Run as Administrator: ```conda activate py27``` then ```conda install -c esri arcgis```.

Comment: I used anaconda prompt as you suggested, but I still have a lot of failures. Namely, it says `If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.`
I don't know what should I do next...

Comment: In the prompt, do you see a line called ```Specifications:```? It's probably telling you that you need a compatible version(s) of python to run ```arcgis```. Sorry, I think I'm muddying the waters here. Please see my edit.

Comment: Yes, `Specifications:

  - arcgis -> python[version='3.4.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0']

Your python: python=2.7

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.`

Answer (score 0):

- **You could try switching environments** to the directory where your current python environment is located. For example, if you are using ArcGIS Pro your *.exe file is normally found here: `C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3`

https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment

> To work with an existing environment in Spyder, you need to change Spyder’s default Python interpreter. To do so, click the name of the current environment in the status bar, and then click Change default environment in Preferences.

> This will open the Preferences dialog in the Python interpreter section. Here, select the option Use the following Python interpreter, and use the dropdown below to select your preferred environment. If its not listed, use the text box or the Select file button to enter the path to the Python interepreter you want to use. See the IPython Console for more information.

> Click Restart kernel in the Consoles menu for this change to take effect.

- **Or you could install Anaconda**, which comes with Spyder, and create a new environment. That way you could start fresh and install whatever packages you like, including arcpy. `conda install -c esri arcgis`

This [cheat-sheet](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf) is handy once you've installed Anaconda.

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/

---

**Edit:**

Since you're still using ArcMap v.??? try pointing to your python environment that comes with the ArcMap installation from the Spyder Preferences menu. Sorry, I've moved on from ArcMap and Python 2.x years ago (wink).

- https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python/importing-arcpy.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_5E64CCAB40C24B0DB1ED80EF96176F73

Answer (score 0):

ArcGis Pro with Python 3.x have Anaconda and Spyder installed. Older ArcGis Desktop with python 2.x Do not have Anaconda/Spyder installed. I think it's impossible to install ArcPy as library. It's only working within python environment delivered with ArcGIS.